# How to override Content-Security-Policy for a specific action

Tags: content-security-policy, hanami

I can obviously change the `Content-Security-Policy` in `views/application.rb`. I can also add a different `Content-Security-Policy` for development mode.

How I can use a different `Content-Security-Policy` for a specific action/actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Security-Policy` is a HTTP header, so it's related to actions, not views.

You can set a global value in `apps/web/application.rb` like this:

```
security.content_security_policy '...'
```

You can set a global value, per environment basis in `apps/web/application.rb`:

```
configure :development do
  security.content_security_policy '...'
end
```

You can set a different value for a given action:

```
module Web::Controllers::Home
  include Web::Action

  def call(params)
    headers.merge!('Content-Security-Policy' => '...')
  end
end
```

If you have many actions that need that same exception you can do:

```
# apps/web/controllers/csp_rule.rb
module Web::Controllers::CSPRule
  def self.included(action)
    action.class_eval do
      before :set_content_security_policy
    end
  end

  private

  def set_content_security_policy
    headers.merge!('Content-Security-Policy' => '...')
  end
end
```

And you can include it where needed.